# Adding Parameter to Angular router.navigate

Tags: angular, typescript, binding, router

First of all, I am not sure if this is the right way, to achieve what I want..
I am trying to add an export binding like the following to a router.navigate()-method:

```
<call [caller]="caller"></call>
```

The problem is that I never use the  directive, but instead adress it through a router:

```
acceptCall() {
   this.router.navigate(["call"]);
}
```

How can I achieve the same export binding from the first example in the acceptCall()-method?
I Have already added an Input() variable and tried it with queryParams like this:

```
@Input() caller: Caller;
acceptCall(caller) {
    this.router.navigate(["call"], {queryParams: caller});
}
```

But this does not work.

Comment: Almost ! try `this.router.navigate(["call", caller]);`

Comment: Doesnt work for me, Do I have to modify my RouterModule.forRoot? mine currently looks like: { path: 'call', component: CallComponent }

Comment: Well yes, `{path: 'call/:caller'}` and you can get it with `this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => this.myParam = params['caller']);` in your subcomponent (route is an ActivatedRoute)

Comment: I have updated my module, but dont quite get the other stuff :D Where do you declare Params , myParam? could you maybe provide a full code example of the class as an answer?

Comment: @reveN: it's not very obvious how your code is organized. It would be easier to help you if you said clearly where all the bits of code you provided are located.

Comment: In my app.module.ts I got my RouterModule with {path ....}
In my parent.component I Import my Caller Object and want to inject it with the acceptCall-method to my child.component.ts, where I want to use the Caller object to get for example the phonenumber and the name of the caller

Answer (score 55):

Following my comments you have to :

1 - Redefine your route

```
{path: 'call/:caller', component: MyComponent }
```

2 - Change your navigation **in the parent component**

```
this.router.navigate(["call", caller]);
```

3 - **In the child component**, get the param

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
// code until ...
myParam: string;
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
// code until ...
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => this.myParam = params['caller']);
}
```

Comment: mhh Ive done everything exactly as you said, but my router roots now back to my "home"-component instead of the call-component, when I call the method

Comment: I used calls like `this.router.navigate(['../user', id], { relativeTo: this.route });` to be sure that it would redirect to the right url. Could you try it ?

Comment: ive created a mock caller and get the following error:
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'call;Id=1;Name=Frodo%20Baggins;Tel=12345%2F678910;Company=The%20Fellowship%20of%20the%20Ring'

Comment: so I get all the caller information I want, but I want to use it inside the component, not the URL

Comment: Oh ! Then use either a service or a Parent-Child relation. route params aren't made for that.

Comment: Or maybe you can use the `ActivatedRoute.data` property, but I've never used it. [Find more here](https://angular.io/guide/router#activatedroute-the-one-stop-shop-for-route-information)

Comment: just for completeness, you also need to import Params from @angular/router

Comment: Coment with `this.router.navigate(['../user', id], { relativeTo: this.route });` helped me (I used `ActivatedRoute` for `router` ). It will be good to be included in answer.

Comment: thanks!! only a detail, is necessary add Params: import { ActivatedRoute , Params} from '@angular/router';